# how to enum friend in my class

Tags: c++, oop, enums, encapsulation, friend

i have the following two  classes :

```
class A{
enum ee{a = 1, b = 2 , c = 3};
};

class B{
 /*


 */

};
```

Now i want to use enum ee in class B how i to friend enum ee in class A?\

Comment: you can declare enum globaly and create members inside ur class

Comment: You do not need to friend it. enums can be made public. Make it public, and access it as `enum A::ee aEnum`. individual ones can be accessed as `A::a`

Comment: @Jeeva Be aware of enums in the global scope (or even your library namespace). The members spill into the scope and have a tendency to lead to surprises.

Comment: If `ee` is `public` in `A`, you can just have a member in `B` like this: `A::ee enumInB;` and set it with `enumInB = A::c;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could restrict access more selectively using this approach:

```
class B;

class A {
    class inner {
        enum ee {a = 1, b = 2 , c = 3};
        friend class B;
    };
public:
    typedef inner exposed;
};

class B {
    void f() {
        const A::exposed::ee e(A::exposed::a);
    }
};
```

this introduces restrictions above the other options, for the times you want/need to be more specific wrt access.

specifically, `A` does not need to be friends with `B` using this approach, and the declarations in `A::inner` are restricted as you have specified. `A::inner` can then keep its declarations private, and allow access via friendship. clients could declare an `inner` (accessed via `A::exposed`), but it will be of no practical use to the client if the enum type and constants are private.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the enum in the public section of `A`, you can refer to it as `A::ee`, and the values as `A::a`, `A::b`, and `A::c.`

```
class A
{
public:
   enum ee {a = 1, b = 2 , c = 3};
};

class B
{  
    A::ee an_enum;
    /*    */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'friend' an enum because enum members are public in its scope. 'Friending' involves making the private members of something public. So, in this case you need to befriend `class A`.

In other words:

```
class A {
    enum ee {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3};

    friend class B;
};
```

will make the private `enum A::ee` accessible from `class B`.

Then, for example:

```
class B {
    void somefunc() {
        enum A::ee v = A::a;
    }
}
```